# Call a user-defined function inside a CTE for every row returned from another CTE

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query with a CTE that returns multiple rows, I want to execute a Function for every row returned.
Is it possible, I checked on google, it says about using temp table to populate the result. I just want to confirm

```
with job_list as (  select JOB_ID,CREATED_DATE from job_table)  ,
app_list as (select APP_ID from job_list jobs, dbo.fnGetApp(jobs.JOB_ID,9))
select * from job_list, app_list
```

This is not the exact query, I have simplified for understanding the problem I face.

`dbo.fnGetApp` is a function that takes two params varchar and int and returns a table  of a single column  (`varchar APP_ID`)

> Error - The multi-part identifier "jobs.JOB_ID" could not be bound.

I want to run the function for every row returned by the `job_list` CTE and use the results as a `CTE` for another query which uses both the `CTEs`

Thanks
David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you do it like this:

```
with job_list as 
(  
   select 
     JOB_ID,
     CREATED_DATE 
   from 
     job_table
),
app_list as 
(
   select 
      APP_ID 
   from 
     job_list AS jobs 
     CROSS APPLY dbo.fnGetApp(jobs.JOB_ID,9) AS something
)
select * from 
job_list, 
app_list
```

Comment: yes, this does it. Did not know about CROSS APPLY, reading about it now. Thanks Arion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method, then you need to use a cursor, but if you want to call a function then you should be able to achieve this with joins.
I might be missing something, but I'm not quite sure why you feel you need to embed a subselect in this code.
The CTE creates the equivalent of a temporary table, and the fields are all accessible to the subsequent query, so simply refer to those fields in your internal function.

Perhaps if you posted the actual query you're using it might make more sense :)

Comment: Arion has suggested CROSS APPLY. I tried that and it works. Thanks